# Generate thumbnails using in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing

I am generating the thumbnails of various image file, now I want to optimize it using thread or queue. so when I select a folder it generate thumb image one by one like in windows search.
I am new to C#, please help me on this.
Thanks,
Tanmoy

Comment: Since you are already generating the image, therefore I think you should update the question to something like... *How to optimize thumbnails generation*

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Task Parallel Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20150531132258/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jbarnes/archive/2009/09/28/visual-studio-2010-net-4-0-parallelism-for-the-masses.aspx) to achieve that. Something like:

[image]

Also, checkout:

- [How to: Create Thumbnail Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-thumbnail-images?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [How To: Creating Thumbnail Images](https://web.archive.org/web/20160525182726/http://www.csharp-station.com:80/Articles/Thumbnails.aspx)

Comment: Liking the use of Paralell.ForEach ;)

Comment: Yes, Parallelizing seems the way to go. Try this search also if you dont have .net4 yet or if you prefer not to use a additional library http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parallelize+c%23

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class (also see [this tutorial](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)) to generate the thumbnails in the background. Something like:

```
BackgroundWorker imageGenerator = new BackgroundWorker()

foreach(var filename in imageFileNames)
{
    imageGenerator.DoWork += (s, a) => GenerateThumbnailMethod(filename);
}

imageGenerator.RunWorkerAsync();
```

This will generate the thumbnails on a separate thread. You can also get the `BackgroundWorker` to let you know when it's done by assigning an event handler to its `RunWorkerCompleted` event. You should do this, because this allows for error checking, as the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` object has an Error property.